# Can't retrieve DB object user by ApplicationUser

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I am new to the ASP.NET MVC4 facing the following problem:

I have a user for whom I have initialized a few objects in the DB.
When that user logs in and tries to retrieve his objects, he gets `null` instead.

Here's the code:

```
public IEnumerable<Course> getListOfCourseAMbyCurrentUser(string currentUserId)
{
    var courses = dc.Courses.Where(course =>
        course != null &&
        course.User.Id == currentUserId);

    if (courses == null) return null;

    return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Course>>(courses);
}
```

I'm till learning about that lambda expression and would appreciate it explained to me.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Well, if you are able to access `User` from `Courses` then a key exists relating the tables. The lambda expression just says to select all of a user's related courses where that course does not equal `null`. If you are receiving a null value, then that user must not have any related non-null courses.

Comment: Thank you so much for the prompt reply.
This line (`course != null &&`) is put there just for debugging.
The thing is I do have `currentUserId`, but when I am trying to find `course.User.Id` that matches `currentUserId` I get nothing. 
Another question: my `Course` among other things defines `FirstName`. I wish I knew how to get into the DB and retrieve `course.User.Id` by that `FirstName` and compare what I am getting, or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

Comment: Are you certain that records do exist for that user?  I'm not sure I understand your second question - since the key exists you will always be able to navigate back to `course.User` fields, even if you wanted to put a condition on it like `course.FirstName == currentFirstName`.

Comment: If you can add all relevant code to the question above it would be much more helpful. 1) Make sure you call `dc.SaveChanges()` when adding records. 2) It's hard to say what all you need to initialize without seeing your tables/relationships. From what you've provided, `Courses` have a foreign key back to the `Users` table and you should be able to retrieve records using what you have above as long as the data exists in both tables.

Comment: Thank you, I think I have found what I was missing: I didn't initialize enough stuff.